# How to accept FormData sent via ajax in Flask?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to send an image file in a FormData using an Ajax POST request.
I am faced with 2 problems:

1. I do not know how to extract the FormData on the flask part
2. I 500 internal server error when making an ajax POST request (not sure if this is because of 1)

Thank you

Flask python code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']
    if file: # and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd()+"/static", "current_image.jpg"))
        return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})
```

HTML and Javascript code:

```
<input id="pictureInput" type=file name=file>
<input type=submit value=Upload id="button">

<script type="text/javascript">
var pictureInput = document.getElementById("pictureInput");
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('pictureFile', pictureInput.files[0]);

$("#button").click(function(){
    console.log(pictureInput);
    console.log(pictureInput.files[0]);
    console.log(myFormData);

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/",
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false, // important
      contentType: false, // important
      dataType : 'json',
      data: myFormData,
      success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
      },
    });
});
</script>
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Add what is the *content* of that 500 response? What is the actual error?

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I just understand what you mean. I have added the error response I got using POSTMAN.

Comment: Well that's different code to what you originally showed; the error is happening on `sys.stdout.write`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to debug it. Now, when using the original code, I got a 'Bad Request - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.'

Comment: Facing the same issue. Unable to access FormData in Flask. Please Let me know if anybody got some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you. **You need to have the `static` folder in the same level as your `app.py` file**

**app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd()+"/static", "current_image.jpg"))
            tasks = []
            return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

tasks is not defined above in your code, so I just initialized it to an empty list. You need also to make sure that jQuery is loaded in your template.

Comment: Hi @ettanany I'm following this same example but if I try to `print(request.files)` I get `ImmutableMultiDict([])`.. any idea on why that is happening? Thanks

Comment: @ettanany `file = request.files['file']` this piece of code wont work because there isnt  a files object on the request, there is a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object of which the file is a part.

Comment: This is not what he is asking in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**1. I do not know how to extract the FormData on the flask part**

In order to extract the fomrdata, you could write the following code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['pictureFile'] # according to the name you append to formdata
```

**2. I 500 internal server error when making an ajax POST request (not sure if this is because of 1)**

Actaully, if the file is not be found, there is no correct response, so it will not work correctly.

You could reference the following sample code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    isSuccess = False
    if 'file' not in request.files:
         return jsonify({"IsSuccess" : isSuccess, "Message": "No file part"})

    file = request.files['pictureFile'] # according to the name you append to formdata

    if file: # and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "static", "current_image.jpg"))

        isSuccess = True
        tasks = [] 
        return jsonify({"IsSuccess" : isSuccess, "tasks": tasks})

 return jsonify({"IsSuccess" : isSuccess, "Message": "Error occurs"})
```